# iOS App testing: No Code signature found

Tags: ios, testing, ipod

I do not have iPhone developer account.
I want to test my app on my iPod Touch.

iPod iOS version      : 5.1 (9B176 build)
Xcode Development SDK : 5.1
Simulators            : iPhone 5.1 Retina/normal
                        iPad 5.1 Retina/Normal

To bypass code signing etc, I changed changed the project settings like below.

```
Code signing identity   Don't code sign
  Debug                 Don't code sign
    Any iOS SDK         Don't code sign
Release                 Don't code sign
  Any iOS SDK           Don't code sign
```

I connected my iPod-Touch to my MacBook Pro, selected iPod as my target (instead simulator), built the project and ran it. 
Then I am getting the error "No Code Signature found."

Any help?

Note: I did not create any app certificate etc. (I don't have app dev account)

Answer (score 54):

You can also get this error if a build gets interrupted partway through. It corrupts Xcode's internal data (why are they saving corruptible data? I have no idea).

Shut down xcode, and restart, do a fresh build ... and it will usually go away.

Comment: it's not a bug - just another Apple feature... :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

## Fully Clean Your Project

It helps if you *fully* clean up build folder. The usual `Project` > `Clean` menu item is not thorough. Use the hidden alternative.

Hold down `Option` key (⌥) while choosing `Product` > `Clean Build Folder…`

The Option key transforms that menu item from "Clean" to "Clean Build Folder" and changes its behavior as discussed in this other question, [XCode 4 “Clean” vs. “Clean Build Folder”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8087065/642706).

Answer (score 9):

You have to code sign if you want to run your app on an iDevice, unless it's jailbroken.

You have to have a development licence to code sign your apps.

If you don't want to buy a developer licence and you are a student, you can apply iOS Developer University Program which allows you to test your apps on actual devices but not to submit App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/

Comment: OK. What if, I want to develop apps for my own purposes to use them on my own iDevice?  Why Apple hates this?

Comment: I hate this situation too. But as you know, this is a question only Apple staff can answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer... If you're not a student though, really, it's just $100, and it's more than worth it. Seriously, if this is your only reason to jailbreak your iOS device, you're just going to get frustrated with it and miss out on new software upgrades later on. It's cheaper (in terms of time and stress), just to buy the developer account.

Comment: If they'll allow the developers to install the app without any code signature, it'll pose two risks. First it'll allow introduction of iOS app markets other than iTunes, which is bad for Apple. Second it'll pose security risk for normal iOS users. So don't think Apple will allow it in near future. If you want these features, you should have bought Android phone instead and as JRG-Developer said, it's just $99 and they'll allow you to unlock 100 devices.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine if you don't want to code sign it in the settings, but you MUST code sign it if you want to run it in a Device. That is of course unless you jailbreak your device... which is your only choice since you mention you do not have an app dev account.

Comment: Please see this post.  "WrightsCS" is telling about a possibility.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning caches and Xcode DerivedData folder helped me to solve this issue. After cleaning product and product build folder exit Xcode and remove everything in

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Then remove all files and folders related to Xcode in

```
~/Library/Caches
```

Comment: Cant believe I didnt try this at first.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your code can not be signed ,so the project can't run in your device .I found this problem because I changed "other C flags" in Build Settings.Remove the item you added ,it runs!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in Xcode 8.2 because I didn't have enough space on my device. Thanks Xcode for the descriptive error...

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when a prov-file was deleted. I generate a provisioning file ,and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with the following file - with the CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED property. By default it is YES. I've changed it to NO - to try to generate an unsigned .ipa.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk [image: The SDKSettings file]

The settings were set to "Don't code sign". After that I needed to run the app on the device, but got this "No Code Signature found" error. After I've set all the teams, profiles, code signing identities correctly - the issue still appeared. Set back the CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to YES.

But somehow nothing helped - "No Code Signature found" error stayed there - had to reinstall the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I Used this:

Right click on XCode.app file in your Application folder and Go to the path :

```
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
```

Open file `SDKSettings.plist` and check value for `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED`. If it is set 'NO' then set it 'YES'.

Now relaunch the XCode. If it does not work again, then clear XCode DerivedData folder.

see : [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60563)