# I want to test my project on Real Device first time... Is need to create Apple ID and Pay $99?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Is there any way to test iphone application on real device without paying $99 to Apple?...

Comment: Pay up or jailbreak device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: agreed, also if at some point you want to sell your app you will need a dev account anyway.

Comment: Try iOS Developer University Program.

See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11972152/624808

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you must have a valid iOS Developer Program in order to test your app on a real device.

**EDIT**

This Answer is not correct any more. You can now enroll as a private person for free in the apple developer program and test your apps on a real device.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.jailcoder.com/

Use this site and jailbreak your device. And It'll work.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question didn't specify "no jailbreaking".

Comment: I have upvote for this question.

Comment: as of today, that link is dead

Answer (score 2):

If you have a friend who has already paid for the $99 program, you can get him to add your device as a test device, then get him to run the app on your device.

You, yourself however, won't be able to build the app from computer since you would need the team developer provisioning profile in order to put the app onto your device.

There are over the air services like TestFlight which makes it easier for your friend to build and send the app to your device, but at the end of the day, someone's got to pay that $99 :D

$99 is reasonable if you have a job and if you are serious about getting into the app development business.

Just a little more insight for you in case you choose to bite the bullet and pay $99. In order to open an iOS developer account, you'll need to have a business name either as a company or a sole trader/individual with your country.

Once you've signed up as a iOS developer, you can begin generating your provision profile so you can put your app on your device.