# Bypass Code-Signing for iOS Test Dev - XCode Version 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm pretty new to the Xcode environment and I'm trying to test a iOS App I'm building.

I'm running XCode 6.0.1 with a non-jailbroken iPhone 6+, running iOS 8.0.
Unfortunately, I do not have a Dev Account as yet, but my iOS simulator is ridiculously slow (and for some reason massive on my screen), making it hard for testing.

I've already tried the solution from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) with no luck, but changing the STRINGs to NO.

I have also tried to change the following project settings ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971875/ios-app-testing-no-code-signature-found?lq=1)), as seen here, with no luck:

[image]

Is there an updated method around this? Or am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: The "huge" problem can be solved by using the Scale option in the Window menu.

Comment: @David Thanks man. How I never found that is beyond me... Shame it only shrinks to 25% though; it's still much easier now though. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: You can shrink it by 25 or 50%, half size works on most monitors now for everything except the 6 plus.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. According to Apple's Documentation on iPhone certificates - iOS/iPhone certificates are only issued to members of the iOS developer program.

Those are the only two options. Without a paid developer account you won't be able to provision your device to run your app, and without jailbreaking your device you can't use the JB-enabled ways (whatever they are) to install your app on your device.