# Unable to install project in real device

Tags: ios, code-signing

unable to install xcode project in real device

Sir After installing pods for Firebase my xcode application is not installing on the ipad but running well in suimulator. I am getting 'no code signature found' popup error in xcode. Pls help

I have tried on/Off xcode and ipad after uninsall previous app.

In my project I have
main project,
.xcodeproj file,
Podfile file,
Pods,
Podfile.lock file &
.xcworkspace file.

Comment: google exact keyword, you will get 100 of results. those will help you.

Comment: open and build the workspace, not the project file.

Comment: Some other great options to try can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971875/ios-app-testing-no-code-signature-found) post

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few steps you can follow:

- Remove all data in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Run pod deintegrate.
- Remove your .xcworkspace if it was created by cocoapods.
- Run pod install or update