# Why Xcode clean command deletes both debug and release mode files?

Tags: xcode, debugging, command, release, code-cleanup

The clean command in XCode, **removes both 'debug' and 'release' mode executables**.
So, I could not compare the output of two modes.

Please suggest, how to 'clean' only the 'selected' mode of files only.

> (Either 'Debug' or 'Release'. Not the both)

Comment: 1. Why do you want to compare? 2. Just remove the directory you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder

Comment: @Shivan Raptor , I need both the build outputs for verification. I need the clean/build to happen through xcode only.