# xcode 6.1 And 7 stops showing variable values while debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I am having one issue related to xCode 6.1 . 
while debugging i put my mouse arrow pointer on the variable but it will show [0] value instead of the actual value. 
when i print it in console window using po command it will show the actual value.

can anybody help me and tell me why its happening?

thank you.

**EDIT**

Even in Xcode 7 it's not working. I am getting same issue in the xcode 7 and above.

[image]

Comment: Try to restart Xcode. Looks like Apple introduced a bug in 6.1.

Comment: @dasdom thank you for quick reply.
i already did that but still getting the same problem i don't know why its happening... :(

Comment: have the same problem :/

Comment: this is because Swift debug in Xcode sucks :) Use `print yourVarName` in console to output value in console

Comment: I am currently using that only and working in objective c but still it's comes up. :( @VitaliyGozhenko

Comment: Did you try doing a clean build of the project and cleaning your derived data folder? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder.

Comment: @xdeleon yes i did that already but not resolved. It's also not resolved in xcode 7 even.