# Can run in ios device but not in ios simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

```
/Applications/Xcode2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:164:1:
Unexpected '@' in program
```

Showing error message `could not build module 'UIKit'`.

If someone knows please help me.

Comment: Reset your simulator and try debug and run again.

Comment: maybe you added `@` in `UITableView.h`in framework by mistake.

Comment: Go to your **Derivedata** folder and remove all the data. then reset the simulator and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the UITableView.h and see if the `@` is added by mistake (most likely)

Quick jump to the file pressing by <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and select `UITableView.h`

**OR** Clean build folder by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as per link here: [XCode 4 "Clean" vs. "Clean Build Folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder)

Comment: Hi ikmal Thanks for your help, i have installed new version of xcode then it  works fine.