# Internal errors in xib files in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, xcode7.1

I have several `xib` files in my iOS project and now that I have upgraded to `Xcode 7.1`, when I build my target, I'm getting errors in some of such `xib` files that say something like:

> Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach all crash logs from ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

Has somebody else experienced this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: clean your project using cmd + shift + k..I think thats bug in xcode

Comment: @EICaptain it looks like... I had to clean and build a couple of times...

Comment: yes...but I think its bug...but you need to clean project couple of time as you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean your xcode, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

Also, Xcode 7.1 is showing some bugs. Send your report on Apple Support.
Also try restarting your XCode.

Comment: In situation like this, it might be worth using - CMD+ALT+SHIFT+K to go a step further and wipe the whole build folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder

Answer (score 1):

Clean: Product-> Clean
Build: Product-> Build and then Archive works for me.