# complication image is displaying too small

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I have a watchkit application with an image. when I place the correctly sized (52x52 pixels for modular small 38mm) image into the correct place in the asset catalog the image displayed is very small, but when I just use a huge version of the image it is scaled down to the size I would expect:

[image: huge asset]
[image: 52x52 asset from 'modular' spot in asset catalog]

any ideas/tips of how should I prepare/use correctly sized images for complications if I don't want to just go with the huge version?

source code: https://github.com/bazik123/Wristlight
ComplicationController.swift -> func imageNamed()

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Are you adding the image to the `Complication/Modular` set in the WatchKit Extension asset catalog? Can you show your code where you assign the modular small template image provider?

Comment: Still unable to reproduce it when code returns named image instead of "bulbmask".   Image is correct size on watchOS 2.1.  Try [Clean Build Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8087065/4151918).

Comment: Did you find a solution or the reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it ended up that the resolutions of my complication images were too high. I had them at 300 and reduced them to 72 using Preview and then they looked perfect!