# XCode can't find symbols for a specific iOS library/framework project

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, symbols

I'm having a problem with breakpoints in the source code of a specific library / framework (new to Xcode - i'm not sure what the correct term is) in a fairly large iOS project.  I have all the code for this library. Breakpoints are working fine everywhere else, but in this one specific library, all breakpoints are ignored.

I can put a breakpoint in a function called from within one of those source files, and it will trigger, but then the callstack shows "__lldb_unnamed_function" for the location in the file i'm interested in, as if the symbols have been stripped.

I have the following settings for the library in question

```
Generate Debug Symbols = YES
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy = NO
Strip Linked Product = NO
Dead Code Stripping = NO
```

I have been using a lot of #ifdefs to test alternate implementations of a few functions so i thought some stuff might be getting marked as dead code by accident (hence that last setting).  I already tried clean/rebuild.  I tried completely removing the app from the target iPhone.  I tried deleting intermediate file folder under

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

The code is definitely executing because all my NSLog calls show up properly.

I don't have much experience with Xcode so i'm hoping i'm just missing something simple

Thanks

Comment: Try to set Symbolic breakpoint

Comment: Thanks, i tried  symbolic breakpoints for several methods but none were triggered.  Had to look up how to set them: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html)

Comment: I did experience the same problem once, and it was caused by Cache stuff as you mentioned above. The methods you tried helped me that time. Did you also tried to clean up Build folder (press Cmd key when Xcode Product menu is dropped down)?

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of that command.  Although it seems to be Option/Alt that you have to hold down, not Cmd.  I gave it a shot, but no help.  The distinctions between Clean and Clean Build Folder [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder)

Comment: you're right, I meant Alt key of course)

Answer (score 1):

Some part of your build process must be stripping this binary.  If you were generating an unstripped binary with no debug information, then you would see full symbol names in backtraces and the like, you just wouldn't have debug information for them.

The only good way to figure out who is doing this is to look at the full build log in Xcode, and expand each of the stages and grub through all the build stages to figure out who is doing this.  You expand the stages by hovering over each build line on the RHS and you'll get a disclosure dingus that looks like a bunch of lines on a page; click that to see the real commands.

Another way to finesse this may be to build the dSYM for this framework (by setting the Debug Format to "DWARF + dSYM".)  That should get made before anything gets stripped, so unless whoever is stripping this is being awfully clever this should preserve the debug information.