# missing dSYM files for Instabug

Tags: ios, xcode, instabug

I've inherited a project with several linked frameworks by virtue of gitmodules. For crash tracking we use Instabug. It keeps asking me for symbol files that I can't find. Note that I did manage to get **some** of the dSYM files from iTunes Connect.

An example of what it's asking me is:

> F9E0A7B7-5989-3D98-A6ED-29F8D1B04A9E

Things I've tried that did not work:
1. [can't find symbols  for framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180908/xcode-cant-find-symbols-for-a-specific-ios-library-framework-project)
2. [using DWARF with dSYM Debug Information Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments)
3. built my project using both iOS10 and iOS11

Anyone else encounter this?

I'm using:
Xcode 9
Build target: iOS10

Comment: Does this uuid belong to your app or a 3rd party app or instabug it self ?

Comment: i'm not sure where the uuid belongs to. is there a way to check?

Comment: I can't really help you, cause I don't have enough information, but here's a hint, try to inspect the ajax calls from your browser, you might find what you're looking for.

Comment: If the UUID is required so it belongs to application frames. also you could contact Instabug support and they will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled Bitcode, you can find the dSYMs inside your app's archive.

You can find the archive via the Xcode `Organizer` window, by selecting your app in the list on the left side of the window. Once you find the archive, right click on it and select `Show in finder`.

In the finder, right click on the archive file and select `Show Package Contents`. In there somewhere there should be a folder named `dSYMs`.