# Error while compiling the project with an Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.3

I have a problem when I try to compile my project on real device. It says build succeeded and then I get the error below.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Agrume.framework/Agrume   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E3ABC8B5-A3C0-4FE3-B395-6A171C9E0EF6/myapp.app/myapp
>   Reason: image not found (lldb)

I tried to add the framework in the settings Build Phases/Build settings but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to clean build folder (opt + shift + cmd + k).

Comment: I've cleaned/built the project like thousands of times and nothing. Also when in general i added the framework (Embedded Binaries) i get the PBXCp error

Comment: As a confirmation, make sure that you have cleaned the build folder, not only a "clean". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087065/xcode-4-clean-vs-clean-build-folder

Comment: Yes, I've done clean build and nothing.

Comment: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData .. remove all derived data from xcode and then try with clean and build project.

Comment: Doesn't work too

Comment: Does this work on simulator? and how are you getting framework? (direct download, carthage, etc.)

Comment: No, on simulator I get the same error..

Comment: @kjeraska your question says, on real device. Please be mindful when you ask question and put as much relevent details. That will save everyones time and get you answer quicker

Comment: @kjeraska how did you get framework? are you using carthage or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not embedding the framework in your application.

Look at the General settings for your application target. There should be a section called "embedded binaries". Add your linked framework to that, and it should be OK. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: In the comment above I mentioned that I have done this. When I add it, I get the PBXCp error.

Comment: @kjeraska You should edit the question to put that information in it because otherwise people like me might miss it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was only fixed by rebuilding the used framework with newer swift version (4.0.3 -> 4.1). I had to download the library source and make a build myself.

Comment: Hi how to make new build from using library

Comment: I am having the same issue framework compiled in swift 4.0 not able to use with swift 4.1

Comment: Your help is much needed